# Weblogic12c ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, weblogic

We are working on upgrading `weblogic` was from 11g to 12c.

But there's a problem. If you start the deployment after installing it on Weblogicwas, you will get the error as below.

```
weblogic.management.deploymentexception:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.springframework.contet.applicationContextAware
```

The reason for the error is that the above logs are coming out, and the system I'm working on is not using spring-framework, but using its own framework, and I don't know why there's a spring-framework error like this.

```
<BEA-149205> <Failed to initialize the application "systemname" due to error weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.throwAppException(BaseDeployment.java:132)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:244)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:65)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppDeployment.prepare(AppDeployment.java:166)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doPrepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:41)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.prepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:193)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$1.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:31)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments$2.doItem(ConfiguredDeployments.java:741)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.parallel.BucketInvoker.invoke(BucketInvoker.java:138)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionAppsParallel(ConfiguredDeployments.java:749)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.prepare(ConfiguredDeployments.java:363)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:232)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:219)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:133)
    at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1287)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:333)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:375)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:212)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:235)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:212)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:235)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:212)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:235)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1237)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1168)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:678)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:652)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1029)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:101)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:496)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:71)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:53)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClassInternal(GenericClassLoader.java:1113)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1046)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1038)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:101)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:496)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:71)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:53)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.loadClass(PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.java:366)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.access$100(PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.java:58)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow$CollectorFilter.accept(PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.java:351)
    at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.getAnnotatedClasses(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:720)
    at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.getAnnotatedClassesByTargetsAndSources(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:664)
    at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.getAnnotatedClassesByTargetsAndSources(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:639)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.processAnnotations(PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.java:288)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.processPOJOsInModuleScopes(PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.java:229)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.prepare(PojoAnnotationProcessingFlow.java:73)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:241)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:65)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppDeployment.prepare(AppDeployment.java:166)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doPrepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:41)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.prepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:193)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$1.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:31)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments$2.doItem(ConfiguredDeployments.java:741)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.parallel.BucketInvoker.invoke(BucketInvoker.java:138)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionAppsParallel(ConfiguredDeployments.java:749)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.prepare(ConfiguredDeployments.java:363)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:232)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:219)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:133)
    at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1287)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:333)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:375)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:212)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:235)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:212)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:235)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:212)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:235)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1237)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1168)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:678)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:652)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
```

Comment: Are you sure it's *your* application that's causing the error and not another one that's deployed on the same application server?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca There are five weblogic domain configurations in one server. But I'm the only web-logic domain that doesn't use spring-framework.
I don't use spring-framework, but I get the error message like this.

Comment: @Kain : Please give the entire stacktrace that you got in the logs. Also update your question with some relevant details like  WEBLOGIC_JAVA_VERSION, APPLICATION_JAVA_VERSION, OS details, DB Version if any, MQ connectivity if any , MQ_VERSION if true, etc

Comment: @Som Full log uploaded successfully.
The weblogic server jdk is 1.8 and the currently compiled source jdk is 1.7. Server os is Linux.

Comment: definitely "systemname" app is pointing to spring-framework in some way. You may check systemname about these dependencies through WLS-CAT (or in pom.xml), remember that Java classes/libraries may have indirect dependencies.

Comment: I have some questions, are you following an Oracle's certified procedure to migrate this application from 11g into 12c? Have you checked all your application's dependencies to be sure it does not use Spring Framework? Could you enable -verbose:class and then restart the server to see all the classes your application is trying to load?